# jQuery/Ajax Load external page into content div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load

I have a website that i wan't to load external html content into my `index.html <div id="content">` without having to refresh the page. I manage to do this with jQuery load() function. When i read up on `load()` and `ajax()`, it has come to my understanding that ajax is a more configurable function then load, but do basically the same thing (correct me if im wrong*). When I use load() the external content loads but the url address doesn't show the current page. Therefore I want to ask if someone out there can show me how i can:

- Make the ajax() function behave like load().
- Show dynamically and fetch href in url for bookmark etc.

Ajax() code example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/ReSdd5U6dOYbQxctzvk7?p=preview

Load() code example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/gpsZbOip0VtO7iXTPaM2?p=preview

Questions? ask!

Thanks beforehand!

/E.

Comment: If I follow your question, then I think what you are looking for is jQuery **load()** and the browser History_API.  Check out : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: Take a look at jquery.fn.load source: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.fn.load
 You will understand how you can make ajax() function behave like load()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it, you are looking to use jQuery **load()** or an equivalent **AND** have the browser history (address bar) update to reflect the url of the just loaded content.

Since you suggest that you have **load()** working, then what you are after is the browser **History_API**, specifically **pushState()**.

You can read more about the : [History_API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

You can also read about the : [pushState() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method)

Based on your **load()** example, I think you can extend it with the following to get what you are after:

```
$('#content').load('link1.html');
$('a').click(function(e){
  var page = $(this).attr('href');
  $('#content').load(page + '.html');

  var stateObj = {loaded : page};
  history.pushState(stateObj, "page title", page + '.html');

  return false; // don't follow the link
});
```

You can also see Mozilla's [AJAX based navigation example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API/Example) that does what I think you are looking to do via AJAX rather than jQuery and uses pushstate.

Answer (score 0):

You may do something like:

```
$('#btn1').click(function(e){
   var href = this.href;  // get href from link

   $.ajax({
       url: href,
       type: 'GET',
       dataType: 'html',
       success: function(data){
         $('#content').html(data);
       }
   });

   return false; // don't follow the link
```

});

Answer (score 0):

None of those options/functions will update the URL shown by the browser... they just load and show the content of the page you requested to the current one.

For history purpose what you could do is to use the native "history API" as explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API), but still, no URL update...